# What's the development status of Hera?

Tags: ewasm

- If I ran Hera on my ETH node instead of the EVM, will it break the
  node? I.e., is it buggy?
- Are there significant performance differences between Hera and
  the EVM as of right now?
- I cannot find any critique / evaluation of Hera anywhere online, can
  someone provide some resources?

Thank you.

Comment: Wait Hera is "third-party application"? Isn't it being developed by the ETH core team? It is in the ETH core Github as one of the implementations of eWASM. ????